# Composite primary keys and influence on natural/surrogate keys usage

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-design

I have a fairly simple question about natural/surrogate key usage in a well-defined context which manifests itself often, and that i'm going to illustrate.

Let's assume you are designing the DB schema for a product using SQL Server 2005 as DBMS. For the sake of simplicity let's say there are only two entities involved, which have been mapped to 2 tables, Master and Slave.

Assume that:

1. We can have **0..n** Slave entries for a single Master's row;
2. Column set **(A, B, C, D)** in Master is **the only candidate** for primary key;
3. Column **B** in Master is **subject to changes** over time;
4. A, B, C, D are a **mix** of varchar, decimal and bigint columns.

The question is: how would you design keys/constraints/references for those tables?
Would you rather (*argumenting your choice*):

1. Implement a composite **natural key** on Master on (A, B, C, D), and a related composite foreign key on Slave, or
2. Introduce a **surrogate key** K on Master, let say an **IDENTITY(1,1)** column with a related (single column) foreign key on Slave, adding a UNIQUE constraint on Master's (A, B, C, D), or
3. Use a different approach.

As for me I'd go with option 2), mainly because of assumption 3) and performance-wise, but I'd like to hear someone else's opinion (since there is quite an open debate on the topic).

Comment: Edited: column set (A, B, C, D) in Master is **the only candidate** for primary key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either 1,2 or 3. There isn't necessarily enough information to determine whether a surrogate is necessary or how useful it might be. Are any of the compound key attributes also part of some key or constraint in the Slave table? Is there some other key of Master that could be used as a foreign key? The fact that a key value may change shouldn't be the deciding factor because any key value may need to change - surrogates are no exception.

> there is quite an open debate on the
>   topic

Unfortunately, much of that debate is based on the mistaken assumption that you need to choose between either a surrogate or a natural key. As your option 2 rightly suggests you can use both as the need arises. One is not a substitute for the other because simple keys and compound keys on different attributes obviously mean different things in your data model and enforce different constraints on your data.

Answer (score 8):

I'd go for option 2. Keep it simple.

It ticks the boxes (narrow, numeric, unchanging, strictly monotonically increasing) for a useful clustered index (which is the default of PKs in SQL Server).

You need to force the uniqueness on `A,B,C,D`, though, to preserve data integrity, as noted.

There is nothing conceptually wrong with option 1, but as soon as you require more indexes on "master" then the wide clustered key becomes a liability. Or more work to determine which index is best as clustered.

Edit:

In case of any confusion

> the choice of which index is clustered is separate to the choice of key

Comment: When designing or creating a table or primary key the database designer/developer/DBA decides what the clustered index should be. There is no sense in choosing a primary key because it also happens to be a good candidate for a clustered index. Choosing primary keys and clustered indexes are separate decisions and should be kept separate.

Comment: @dportas: correct, it's an implementation decision not a modelling issue. In practice it doesn't matter so much for the average mickey mouse database or where there is no "DB" team.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but if you agree that the choice of key shouldn't be determined by the choice of clustered index then I don't think you've answered the OP's question. As I read it, your answer seems to support the misconception that primary key choice should be determined by what it is a good choice of clustered index. Making the distinction is important because so many people seem to get confused over the difference between keys and indexes.

Comment: If you want to keep things as simple as possible, then surrogates are precisely what you should never do.  There is nothing simple about surrogates, except if you simply fail (or refuse) to understand the problems they introduce.  Think about updating the "slave" table under an optimistic locking scenario (you have to check that the surrogate ID value at update time still stands for the same A,B,C,D natural key value as it did when the data was retrieved).

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption (3) tends to suggest option (2) because it is inconvenient and potentially time consuming to deal with cascading updates of the primary key of Master when B changes.

Of course it depends on how often this will occur: if it is something that you expect to happen "all the time" then it suggests (A,B,C,D) is a poor choice of primary key; on the other hand, if it will only rarely happen, then (A,B,C,D) may be a good choice of primary key, and having those columns in Slave may have some advantages (no need to join to Master all the time to find out those column values).

Answer (score 0):

**Three.**

The first suggestion could be drop composte keys and add a new field for an automatic key, that is not related to the other fields. To both master and detail table.

*It could be an integer autoincrement key or a Global Unique Identifier. Keeping composite keys in any S.Q.L. server brand, is dificult, and sometimes innecesarily difficult.*

*But, if you need to keep the composite key in the master table, you may still wonder how to deal with the slave table primary key. Many developers usually take the same fields for the primary key, from the master table, put it on the slave / detail table, and add an additional consecutive integer key. But, as you mention, if you have to change the key for master table, and keep the already existing detail rows, you get into trouble with the referencial integrity constraints.*

Summary: I suggest, add a new field for the slave table, that is not related to the master table, add a foreign key of fields to the slave / detail table, that references the master table. Keep the detail primary key and the foreign key to master table, independant.